# How to change logitech c920 webcam settings using c++ on osx?

Tags: c++, macos, webcam, osx-mavericks, openframeworks

I'm trying to control auto focus/auto white balance settings for a webcam using OpenFrameworks(a c++ framework), but not having any luck.

The framework provides a QTKit video grabber, but I can't use the settings.
There is a videoSettings() function when calling that I get an alert mentioning the project must be compiled with the 10.6 sdk and is not supported when the app is compiled with 10.7+

I'm using openFrameworks 0.8.0 on osx 10.9 and haven't found an easy way to download the 10.6 sdk( There is no direct download (older versions of xcode an sdk download option), I've downloaded Xcode 4.1 but it can't be installed because of osx 10.9).

I've also tried to set the GStreamer grabber, but I get linking errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "ofGstVideoGrabber::ofGstVideoGrabber()", referenced from:
      testApp::setup() in testApp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

however, I thought the dylibs in the GStreamer framework are also usable for i386:

```
file /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib/libgstbase-1.0.0.dylib 
/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers:                                 directory
/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib/libgstbase-1.0.0.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib/libgstbase-1.0.0.dylib (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib/libgstbase-1.0.0.dylib (for architecture i386):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

I've tried dragging the framework into the 3rd party frameworks folder and adding the paths to Header Search Paths and Library Search Paths in Xcode but no joy.

I've tried using ofQuickTimeGrabber but got a parsing error:

```
Unknown type name 'ofQuickTimeGrabber'
```

After tried [ofxUVC](https://github.com/atduskgreg/ofxUVC/) which uses ofxQTKitGrabber but ran into errors again:

```
Field type 'ofxQTKitVideoGrabber' is an abstract class
```

Ideally I would like to control resolution (16:9 formats seem a bit deformed/scaled) and autofocus for the c920 webcam.
Is that possible with my setup on osx 10.9 ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download an older version of XCode (the last version of 3 or 4 depending on if you want 10.6 or 10.7 SDKs) from the Apple developer site (https://developer.apple.com/downloads/), it will contain the 10.6 and/or 10.7 SDKs (inside the package).

You can extract the SDKs without installing the full package (which will be disallowed on 10.9).  There are several ways to do this, but the easiest I've found is to use Pacifist http://www.charlessoft.com/.

Then place both of those sdks in your XCode 5 SDKs folder at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs folder and to use them with XCode 5.

Then restart XCode and choose the 10.6 or 10.7 SDK in the build settings.  Remember to change the SDK for BOTH your project AND the openFrameworksLib project.

Also, to ensure the correct aspect ratio, make sure you are initializing your camera with a specific size (e.g. `grabber.initGrabber(1280, 720);` if you are trying to get a 16:9 aspect from the camera.  By default you are not guaranteed to get the camera's "best" native resolution.

**For documentation purposes**, here are the steps currently needed to get ofxUVC control over the Logitech c920 camera:

1. Add ofxUVC and ofxYAML to the openframeworks addons folder
2. in UVCCameraControl.h set UVC_PROCESSING_UNIT to 3 (`#define UVC_PROCESSING_UNIT_ID 0x03` )
3. in UVCCameraControl.m's [setData](https://github.com/bakercp/ofxUVC/blob/master/src/UVCCameraControl.m#L255) and [getData](https://github.com/bakercp/ofxUVC/blob/master/src/UVCCameraControl.m#L268) modify the [wIndex](https://github.com/bakercp/ofxUVC/blob/master/src/UVCCameraControl.m#L260) to use the selector instead of the unitID (`controlRequest.wValue = (selector << 8) | interfaceNum;`)
4. Update the camera definition in the .yaml file

Logitech c920 definition:

```
- name: Logitech Camera
  vendorId : 0x046d
  productId: 0x82d
  interfaceNum: 0x03
  # 1280x720 (this is 1/2 res)
  width: 1280
  height: 720
```

Note that the Logitech Camera is the id listed by the ofQTKitVideoGrabber in this case
and the `cameraToUse` at the top of the yaml file is set to 6(c920's yaml 0 based index).

This was succesfully tested on osx 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.I've finally managed to compile the project with the 10.6 sdk. Unfortunately no auto focus/auto white balance settings. Looks like I need to figure out how to get ofxUVC to work

Comment: Great glad it worked.  A lot of those specialized features (especially those that are not standardized like IIDC/DCAM) are difficult / impossible to access from the standard drivers.  I'll bet ofxUVC will work.  Also, if you are interested in getting GStreamer installed on OS X and working w/ openFrameworks, check out this: https://github.com/arturoc/ofxGstRTP (check the readme.md).  Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately I still haven't managed to get ofxUVC to work (stuck on the `Field type 'ofxQTKitVideoGrabber' is an abstract class` error because of ofxQTKitVideoGrabber). Any hints on how I could that running ? Thanks!

Comment: I just updated the addon here https://github.com/bakercp/ofxUVC.  It compiles now for me with the new version of openFrameworks.  Check it out.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this! I've finally managed to use ofxUVC from your fork. Still trying to change the settings, but the application hangs with this output: ...

Comment: `DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x3340ab0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x334a6e0
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x334b930, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x334b8f0
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0xe63660, fPowerNotifyPort= 0xe60da0
found cam at index[0]: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
found cam at index[1]: HD Pro Webcam C920
setAutoExposure = 1 
2013-11-25 00:27:39.887 example-ofxUVCDebug[1419:303] CameraControl Error: Control request failed: 00000000`. This when I set `cameraToUse: 6` and added a c920 definition under c910...

Comment: `- name: Logitech c920
  vendorId : 0x046d
  productId: 0x082d
  interfaceNum: 0x02
  # 1280x720 (this is 1/2 res)
  width: 640
  height: 360
` but I'm not sure I did this right. Here's what System Information says about the camera: `HD Pro Webcam C920:

  Product ID: 0x082d
  Vendor ID: 0x046d  (Logitech Inc.)
  Version:  0.11
  Serial Number: 93B630AF
  Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
  Location ID: 0x1a120000 / 4
  Current Available (mA): 500
  Current Required (mA): 500`. If I set camereToUse to 5 the camera is opened and I see c910 listed(although hardware is c920) but no settings are applied...

Comment: ...`setAutoExposure = 1 
2013-11-25 00:34:08.168 example-ofxUVCDebug[1462:303] CameraControl Error: No interface to send request` the error keeps repeating. Perhaps interfaceNum is wrong ? I'm not sure what it means :(

Comment: Hey, honestly, I've never used ofxUVC ... and I don't currently have any cameras to test it with ... so I'd suggest hopping back on the issues page of the original author and see if you can get some help from him (or someone else w/ a cam).  Greg (the author) is a friend and I issued a PR so, hopefully he'll see it and be able to give you a hand or point you in the right direction.

Comment: Cool, will get in touch with Greg. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Great to see that this is working George.  Greg just pulled my changes into the main Repo, so future folks should use the main repo.